# Is there a way to include custom headers in emscripten?

Tags: c, curl, networking, libcurl, emscripten

I've use cURL command-line tool with --libcurl and a url of mine(the url works in normal C), however I get the error "curl.h" does not exist, although it is in the same directory. I can't figure out how to include headers in emscripten. All of the supposed documentation on this usually ends up being about something else entirely.

Comment: even if you get the header to include, what about the actual library?

Comment: You forgot to include an explanation of what you're doing and what error message you got.

Comment: With out posting your code, all we can do is guess.  Suggest also posting your link command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I was being dumb